# SSIS Package failures

Tags: error-handling, ssis, package

I have an SSIS package that loads a CSV, however, I am getting 4 different errors & i've tried multiple times to explore what these could mean and experimented with different data types too. Mainly, the errors seem to be coming from the column (ISEDITABLE) in the CSV - a simple column populated with either 1 or a 0. Any advice on these is welcome... thanks.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "FFSRC_ACCCANDOC" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

---

> An error occurred while processing file "Z:\EnterPriseDWFeederFiles\EPR\Data Warehouse 
>   Extracts\RWH_LR_CNS_ACCCANDOC_01DYS_20160422_0030_V51.csv" on data row 2.

---

> The "output column "ISEDITABLE" (130)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "ISEDITABLE" (130)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

---

> Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "ISEDITABLE" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

Comment: Have you tried altering the "Error Output" from your csv source to ignore Truncation errors? Then you can see what data is being passed through via a Data Viewer

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the truncation error issue you will probably find the other errors "disappear too"!

You are trying to write too much data to the column ISEDITABLE.

I can see that you are creating a CSV file - but you haven't posted any sample data.
Guessing, there are **either or both** additional ',' commas in a column which is shifting your CSV columns across so to speak or you are using text qualifiers such as double quotes '"' but the data actually already contains the text qualifier so, again, your columns are getting shifted across.

So:

1. Find the row causing the error
2. Confirm that the correct data is being written to the ISEDITABLE column.
3. Check that there are no commas in the SQL data. (Assuming comma delimited columns in your output file)
4. Check there are no " in your SQL data. (Asssuming " is the text qualifier.)
5. If that doesn't solve it, please post the offending row of data (and the one before it) on here.